# How can I fix this control box?

Tags: capacitor, motor, transformer

I have an electric adjustable bed, but the electric components just stopped working a few years ago.
calling the company to repair it will cost way too much, so I wanted to finally try to fix it.
I believe that the problem is in the "Control Box" and those are the specs of it(can't upload more than 2 picture...), because nothing is turning on. not the LED on the remote, nothing.

```
Input: 220V-240V~50Hz,4VA
Output1: 22V-...,0.1A
Ouput2: 220V-240V~50Hz
Duty cycle: 10%,max. 2min./18min
```

[image: Control box circuitry and components]

When I opened it, A burnt smell came out of it and I noticed that the capacitor has a dried brown liquid on the bottom. I removed it, and this is how it looks:
[image: Circuit with capacitor dried liquid]

This is the capacitor specs:

```
MIRAN 1000uF 50v -40 +105C
```

**My questions are:**

Can I fix it by just ordering a new capacitor (with the same specs, of course) and solder it to its place?
Will it be safe to do so?
And with what can I clean this liquid, alcohol?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably replacing the cap will be fine. Give it a try, it's a very simple circuit, what else could go wrong?

Comment: Note that there was likely nothing wrong with the capacitor. The dried brown stuff is a "glue" they add after construction to stop it from vibrating.

Comment: Does the component below the (missing) capacitor have four solder points underneath? If so, it is a bridge rectifier containing four diodes - it is suspect as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replace the part.
Yes, it will be safe assuming you use the correct part, put it the correct way around, don't damage anything else and solder it correctly.
Yes, alcohol e.g. isopropanol is the best option for cleaning the board.

Will this fix it? That depends if anything else has gone wrong.

Comment: I know there is know way for you to know, but can something else go wrong if the capacitor burnt out?

Comment: @NoamC: Can? Yes. Is it likely? No.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer,
Where can I buy a good quality capacitor on the cheap?

Comment: The large distributors like RS or farnell will have the parts you need for a reasonable price but you'll probably end up paying more for postage than for the parts. There may be a local shop you can use that will charge twice as much but you avoid the postage, that depends a lot on where you are.

Comment: However, chances are good that something ELSE failed first and the failed capacitor was the end result. For example as mentioned earlier if the bridge rectifier shorted, the fist component to be damaged would be the capacitor, but not necessarily the last. Capacitors are not fuses, their purpose in a system like this is to smooth the DC bus ripple. If the bridge shorted, it also would take out the transistors that are controlling the little PMDC motor and possibly the IC that was controlling those transistors. That would be a lot more difficult to fix.

Comment: I've bought 5 from eBay for 8$ made by Nichcon. I will see how it will turn out becauae it's shipped from my country(Israel). Thank you very much for the quick and helpful comments, if it will work it will save me some  money...